# Functional variation about metric

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, variational-calculus

Recently I’m learning about lagrangian fomulation in GR. And I’m doing some calculations for some toy models.

I precisely understand the variance of christoffel, Riemann tensors about metric, but when it comes to some arbitrary fields, I’m confusing about the manner of their transformation rules.

Suppose that we’ll consider this EM field with source term.

$$L=\sqrt{-g}(-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}+A_\mu J^\mu).$$

Then what is $\frac{\delta A_\mu}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}$ or $\frac{\delta J^\mu}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}$?

Is it zero? but $A_\mu = g_{\mu\nu}A^\nu$ and $J^\mu = g^{\mu\nu}J_\nu$ so it seems not obvious..

So what I confuse is this; for arbitrary tensor fields, we can raise/lower index of tensor with metric. Then how can we judge that this tensor is dependent of metric or not?

Answer (score 1):

OP is right. In order to be able to vary wrt. the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ it is important to know the hidden/implicit dependence of $g_{\mu\nu}$ in various quantities. Be aware that this is fundamentally a matter of conventions.

- Normally the 1-form gauge-potential $A_{\mu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}$ and the EM field strength $\frac{1}{2}F_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{\nu}$ are considered independent of the metric.
- Normally the elementary external source [4-vector density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density) $J^{\mu}$ for $A_{\mu}$ is considered independent of the metric, i.e. it contribute with a term $\pm J^{\mu}A_{\mu}$ in the Lagrangian density.

  If $J^{\mu}$ is a composite 4-vector (density) current of some matter fields in the theory, then $J^{\mu}$ dependent on the metric as specified by the theory at hand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I’m still in struggling. Is there no way to derive the master formula? How can we know that gauge potential is one form rather than covariant vector?

Comment: Oh you mean that is merely the matter of convention? So when we start our formula we can choose whether some arbitrary tensor is invariant under $g_{\mu\nu}$ or not? And what you introduced is some famous convention right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to format. I'm new here.

I'm also very rusty. I'm helping because I'm not sure whether or not someone else will answer.

This is my best thought.

I feel like that term should be

variation of

g_mu_nu A^mu J^nu

which as you said has a term with a partial derivative with respect to g_mu_nu. Then you can use the product rule and chain rule for the other two terms. I believe (but am not certain-- this is something I've only seen a couple of times in GR, more in QFT, but it's been a long time) that those are with respect to an affine parameter.

but here in this expression I think the g_mu_nu term multiplies linearly rather than A and J being functions of g_mu_nu (although they are functions of the coordinates chosen to express g_mu_nu). Then, the derivative with respect to g_mu_nu would be just AJ.

Comment: *I'm not sure how to format.* [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Then why don’t you express source term as $g^{\mu\nu}A_\mu J_\nu$? I’m not sure how can we choose the right answer..

Comment: Because the desired variation was with respect to g_mu_nu not the upper index version. The other answer is also correct in my opinion in this context.

Comment: In other words they say essentially the same thing, and the other answer rephrases my answer, which was earlier, in more technical terms. I am okay with it being chosen as correct. It doesn’t matter to me.